# filtering columns that has different dtype cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styling

I have recently asked a question on applying select_dtypes for specific columns of a data frame.

I have this data frame that has different dtypes on its columns (str and int in this case).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
[-1, 3, 0],
[5, 2, 1],
[-6, 3, 2],
[7, '<blank>', 3 ],     
['<blank>', 2, 4],
['<blank>', '<blank', '<blank>']], columns='A B C'.split())
```

I want to create different masks for strings and integers. And then I will apply stylings based on these masks.

First let's define a function that will help me create my mask for different dtypes. ([Thanks to @jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984032/applying-select-dtypes-for-selected-columns-of-a-dataframe))

```
def filter_type(s, num=True):
    s_new = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
    if num:
        return s_new.notnull()
    else:
        return s_new.isnull()
```

then our first mask will be:

```
mask1 = filter_type(df['A'], num=False) # working and creating the bool values
```

Second mask will be based on an interval of integers:

```
mask2 = df['A'].between(7 , 0 , inclusive=False)
```

But when I run the mask2 it gives me the error:

```
TypeError:'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Note: Stylings I would like to apply is like below:

```
def highlight_col(x):
    df=x.copy
    mask1 = filter_type(df['A'], num=False)
    mask2 = df['A'].between(7 , 0 , inclusive=False)
    x.loc[mask1, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = 'background-color: ""'
    x.loc[mask2, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = 'background-color: #7fbf7f'
```

Comment: Related: [Conditionally format Python pandas cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203959/conditionally-format-python-pandas-cell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is used to set values. You need [`pd.DataFrame.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.style.html) to set styles. In addition, you can use `try` / `except` for a method of identifying when numeric comparisons fail.

Here's a minimal example:

```
def styler(x):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        try:
            if 0 <= i <= 7:
                res.append('background: red')
            else:
                res.append('')
        except TypeError:
            res.append('')
    return res

res = df.style.apply(styler, axis = 1)
```

Result:

[image]